# Array.splice() results in the value 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, actions-on-google

Currently, i'm working on code which should remove the picked option of a user from a list. When I use the `.splice()` method it results in the value `undefined`.

Initially I thought it was an async problem, so I added async code for this.

```js
app.intent("Optionpicker", (conv, input) => {
  conv.data.list = ['optionA', 'optionB', 'optionC', 'optionD']

  let choice = conv.parameters.choice

  async function listremover() {
    let index = conv.data.list.indexOf(choice);
    if (index > -1) {
      conv.data.list = conv.data.list.splice(index, 1);

      return conv.data.list
    }
  }
  listremover().then()

  conv.add(`Ok, your choice is ${choice}. The remaining options are: ${conv.data.list[0]}, ${conv.data.list[1]} and ${conv.data.list[2]}. Which one is next?`)
})
```

My expected result is the function returns an array without the chosen option of the user. At this moment, the value is 'undefined' and crshes the code.

Comment: Why `async` when there's no `await`? And what do you expect to happen here: `listremover().then()`?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) -> Return value: _"An array containing the **deleted elements**. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned."_

Comment: You don't need to reassign the list, simply call splice

Comment: Where do you see `undefined`? This should never be able to return `undefined`. It should always return an array. The only other option is that you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to hard code a few values and remove your `app.intent("Optionpicker", (conv, input) => {` because app, conv, and input are undefined in this example.

```js
let conv = {};
//let choice = 2; // conv.parameters.choice;
// had to hard code values b/c app and conv are undefined in this example
conv.data = {};
conv.data.list = ['optionA', 'optionB', 'optionC', 'optionD'];
let selected = {};

async function listremover() {
  let index = conv.data.list.indexOf('optionB');
  //if (index > -1) {
  //conv.data.list = conv.data.list.splice(index, 1);
  //return conv.data.list;
  //}

  if (index > -1) {
    selected = conv.data.list.splice(index, 1);
    //return selected; // returns selected array
  }
  return conv.data.list; // returns remaining values of original array
}

listremover().then(function(res) {
  // removed `conv.add()` not sure where this is defined...
  //console.log(`Ok, your choice is ${selected}. The remaining options are: ${conv.data.list[0]}, ${conv.data.list[1]} and ${conv.data.list[2]}. Which one is next?`);
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Hi Jay,
Thank you for your reply. This code returns an array of the chosen option and two times 'undefined'. So I need the inverse of this: an array with the remaining options. E.g.: is choice = 'Option A', the returning array should include options B, C and D.

Comment: `Array.splice()` returns an array of the values removed. It removes those values from the original array. So your `conv.data.list` is now an array of all the remaining values. I'll update my answer to illustrate this point.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Jay! Do you have a suggestion to invert the outcomes? So how can I get the array with the not-chosen options?

Comment: `listremover()` is already promise that will return the remaining values of the array (not-chosen options). Please mark as answered.